# Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException Error when running remote driver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have automation project that run local and also on remote 
until now we download the chrome driver version and install it manually to all our remote machines.
Now i want to start use driver nugget , so i download the nugget and instar it into the project , in local it all runs fine , but after I check in the chenges and trying run it on our remote machine I get this error (Im using MSTest):

> Initialization method AutomationTests.BoltAPLConsumer.Ini threw
>   exception. OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException:
>   OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The chromedriver.exe
>   file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the
>   PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html..

it looks like the files not exist for some reason on the machine , why it can be ?

this is driver set up cod :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("test-type");
options.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the downloaded executable [`chromedriver.exe`](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/) current directory on the `PATH` environment variable then run you above code as it is, or you should provide downloaded executable [`chromedriver.exe`](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/) current directory during initialization of [`ChromeDriver`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriver__ctor_6.htm) class as below :-

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("test-type");
options.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
driver = new ChromeDriver(@"path\to\chromedriver.exe location", options);
```

**Note** :- You can download latest [chromedriver.exe for here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/)

**Note** :- Obsolete [`ChromeDriver`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) URL here.

Comment: So why it run fine in local testing ?

Comment: @user2450821 what do you mean local and remote?? you are using ChromeDriver which runs locally.. so what do you mean by remote actually??

Comment: Im running the test on remote machine using MSTest .

Comment: You are running test on remote machine but you are using ChromeDriver which wants s chromedriver location to run on that remote machine, you need to set chromedriver path at remote machine as well to run this test, may be in your local machine where you tested it is already set, but you need to set there also..without chromedriver path it's impossible to run because ChromeDriver wants executable driver to talk with browser..:)

Comment: When you run test in your local machine `ChromeDriver` searches executable driver on you local machine but when you run same test on remote machine `ChromeDriver` searches executable driver on that remote machine..you need to set driver location into PATH environment there also..:)

Comment: i add the path to the solution and i still getting the same error :(

Comment: i just add the driver exe to the solution, and after this i add the path to the code  driver = new ChromeDriver(somePath,options);

Comment: @user2450821 could you share your `somePath` value...in `somePath` variableyou need to assign only  location of the chromedriver.exe...